# What is the error I'm making using the product rule of limits for $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(n!)^\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm aware that the limit for $(n!)^\frac{1}{n}$ is $\infty$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$.

However using $n!=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(2)(1)$, $(n!)^\frac{1}{n}=n^\frac{1}{n}(n-1)^\frac{1}{n}\cdots2^\frac{1}{n}$.

Now $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n^\frac{1}{n} =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(n-1)^\frac{1}{n}=\cdots=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}2^\frac{1}{n} = 1$.

Using the product rule of limits, the product of these limits would give $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(n!)^\frac{1}{n}$. However this is incorrect and I'm unsure as to where I'm making the error.

Comment: It's like saying $1/n + 1/n + \cdots + 1/n$ (n summands) should $\to 0,$ since each summand $\to 0.$

Comment: you can apply that only when the number of terms is fixed (not depending on $n$)

Comment: Just to add to the already nice comments: $1^n = 1$ for all $n \geq 1$, but $1^{\infty}$ is indeterminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinite product of terms that tend to $1$ is not necessarily $1$.

More precisely: Let $p(n) = \prod_{k=1}^n a_k(n)$ with $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_k(n) =1$ for each $k$. Does this imply $p = \lim_{n\to \infty} p(n) = 1$ ? The answer is no.

A counterexample: $a_k(n)= e^{1/n}$